# Best way to move cursor to start of variable declaration?

Tags: cursor-movement

There are a lot of times were I have something like `int x = someFunction(a, b, c);` If my cursor is somewhere after the equals sign, is there a good way to put the cursor on the “s” in someFunction?

All the options I’ve tried suck. F=ll has too many keypresses far away from each other, spamming B until I get there is dumb and doesn’t work with macros, and counting words and doing (number)B ruins the workflow because I have to stop and count words.

Comment: `F=ll has too many keypresses` Create a mapping. Sort of `nnoremap F F=w`.

Comment: Do you like `F(b` any better? `Fs`?

Comment: Or how about `%b`? `F=w`?

Comment: I like `%b`, Rich. Besides being short and pretty easy to type, a double `%`   (`%%b`) will get you there if you start to the left of the left parens